# R.Swift - Cannot call value of non-function type StringResource

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

Anyone experienced with using R.Swift who could help? I'm trying to consolidate code in our project which uses tons of `R.string.localizable` so that their occurrences aren't strewn all over the code and so that strings (and images) don't need to be reinstantiated again and again. For this I want to add static lazy structs, like so:

```
private struct Text
{
    static let text1 = R.string.localizable.text1()
    static let text2 = R.string.localizable.text2()
    static let text3 = R.string.localizable.text3()
    static let text4 = R.string.localizable.text4
}
```

This works with simple strings but a problem arises when any of those string resources require arguments, like in case of `text4` which therefore is declared as a `String Resource` and not a `String`:

R.generated.swift:

```
static let text4 = Rswift.StringResource(key: "some.username", tableName: "Localizable", bundle: R.hostingBundle, locales: ["en", "ja"], comment: nil)
```

When `text4` is required and I try to use it through my Text struct I get the error:

```
_userNameLabel?.text = Text.text4(userName, String.Empty)
```

Error: `Cannot call value of non-function type StringResource`

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
static func text4(_ value: Int) -> String {
     R.string.localizable.text4(value)
}
```

and call `Text.text4(10)`

Comment: this is it! Thanks!